# Some keys are not reading by onkeyup and onKeyDown in Android

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode

If we pressed the division symbol and multiplication symbol in Android Soft keyboard, then the onKeyup() and onKeydown() in android is not working.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `OnKey()` instead; I think it might work.